# Dynamic SQL without having to use fully qualified table names in SQL (Openrowset?)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a large set of pre-existing sql select statements.

From a stored procedure on [Server_A], I would like to execute each of these statements on multiple different SQL Servers & Databases (the list is stored in a local table on [Server_A] , and return the results into a table on [Server_A].

However, I do not want to have to use fully qualified table names in my sql statements.  I want to execute "select * from users", not "select * from ServerName.DatabaseName.SchemaName.Users"

I've investigated using Openrowset, but I am unable to find any examples where both the Server name and DatabaseName can be specified *as an attribute of the connection*, rather than physically embedded within the actual SQL statement.

Is Openrowset capable of this?  Is there an alternate way of doing this (from within a stored procedure, as opposed to resorting to Powershell or some other very different approach?)

**The inevitable "Why do I want to do this?"**

- You can do it (specify the server and database in the connection
  attributes and then use entirely generic sql across all databases) in
  virtually every other language that accesses SQL Server.
- Changing all my pre-existing complex SQL to be fully qualified is a
  huge PITA (besides, you simply shouldn't have to do this)

Comment: Why not use fully qualified names? Asking for a friend.

Comment: ddddd sorry dont know how to erase a comment

Comment: Why not use fully qualified?  Ummmmm, because I'm executing large pre-existing non-fully-qualified SQL against multiple databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done quite easily via SQLCLR. If the result set is to be dynamic then it needs to be a Stored Procedure instead of a TVF.

Assuming you are doing a Stored Procedure, you would just:

- Pass in `@ServerName, @DatabaseName, @SQL`
- Create a `SqlConnection` with a Connection String of: `String.Concat("Server=", ServerName.Value, "; Database=", DatabaseName.Value, "; Trusted_Connection=yes; Enlist=false;")` or use `ConnectionStringBuilder`
- Create a `SqlCommand` for that `SqlConnection` and using `SQL.Value`.
- Enable Impersonation via `SqlContext.WindowsIdentity.Impersonate();`
- `_Connection.Open();`
- undo Impersonation -- was only needed to establish the connection
- `_Reader = Command.ExecuteReader();`
- `SqlContext.Pipe.Send(_Reader);`
- Dispose of Reader, Command, Connection, and ImpersonationContext in `finally` clause

This approach is less of a security issue than enabling Ad Hoc Distributed Query access as it is more insulated and controllable. It also does not allow for a SQL Server login to get elevated permissions since a SQL Server login will get an error when the code executes the `Impersonate()` method.

Also, this approach allows for multiple result sets to be returned, something that [OPENROWSET](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) doesn't allow for:

> Although the query might return multiple result sets, OPENROWSET returns only the first one.

---

**UPDATE**

Modified pseudo-code based on comments on this answer:

- Pass in `@QueryID`
- Create a `SqlConnection` (_MetaDataConnection) with a Connection String of: `Context Connection = true;`
- Query _MetaDataConnection to get `ServerName`, `DatabaseName`, and `Query` based on `QueryID.Value` via `SqlDataReader`
- Create another `SqlConnection` (_QueryConnection) with a Connection String of: `String.Concat("Server=", _Reader["ServerName"].Value, "; Database=", _Reader["DatabaseName"].Value, "; Trusted_Connection=yes; Enlist=false;")` or use `ConnectionStringBuilder`
- Create a `SqlCommand` (_QueryCommand) for _QueryConnection using `_Reader["SQL"].Value`.
- Using _MetaDataConnection, query to get parameter names and values based on `QueryID.Value`
- Cycle through `SqlDataReader` to create `SqlParameter`s and add to _QueryCommand
- `_MetaDataConnection.Close();`
- Enable Impersonation via `SqlContext.WindowsIdentity.Impersonate();`
- `_QueryConnection.Open();`
- undo Impersonation -- was only needed to establish the connection
- `_Reader = _QueryCommand.ExecuteReader();`
- `SqlContext.Pipe.Send(_Reader);`
- Dispose of Readers, Commands, Connections, and ImpersonationContext in `finally` clause

Comment: Wow, this is the type of answer I was hoping for!  Question:  via SQLCLR, can I do dynamic SQL including a parameters collection (built from metadata) whose members would be populated at runtime from parsing a delimited Parameter:Value string as you can in C#, and unlike how you have to know at design time with SqlServer (except when using openrowset)?

Comment: @tbone Well, Yes, **BUT** you are underestimating what can be done in pure T-SQL. 1) You can do "dynamic" params to a proc by passing in XML, a delimited list, or a TVP. 2) You can supply a dynamic list of parameters to `sp_executesql` by treating the call to `sp_executesql` as a 2nd level of Dynamic SQL. Which means you can also dynamically inject the database name via `SET @SQL = 'EXEC [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.sp_executesql @Query, @ParamList, ' + @ParamVals;` and not need fully qualified objects ;-). But this is just FYI since that doesn't get you the remote server piece.

Comment: @tbone Also, if the params are stored in the DB, then why query for them, concat them into a delimited K/V Pair string, pass them in, only to parse them out into what amounts to a 2 column table? Just pass in the QueryID or whatever you use to grab those values, and then `SELECT ParamName, ParamValue FROM ParamTable WHERE QueryID = @QueryID;` in the .NET code, then just cycle through the SqlDataReader getting the discrete field values. It's less work and less error-prone :-). You might even be able to get ServerName and DatabaseName in the SQLCLR proc, so pass in only @QueryID to the proc.

Comment: I'm already doing the K/V part (for setting parameter values generically).  As you note, the extremely important missing piece in your answer above is the remote server part.  The goal is to entirely remove any full qualification or token replacement for Server and Database within @SQL.

Comment: Do you know enough about SQLCLR to know if one can entirely abstract away the Server and Database specification away from the SQL, just as you can in say C#, ADO, etc?

Comment: @tbone That is what I have been describing. SQLCLR = C# (or VB.Net). So, yes :-). The example I gave in my answer shows this as Server and Database name are used to build the connection string. I was merely pointing out in the last comment that they don't even need to be passed into the SQLCLR proc; only the QueryID (or whatever) needs to be passed in. From there, the Server, Database, main query, and optional parameter names and values, can be queried. From that you build the Connection String and the SQL. The only thing you need to handle in the T-SQL side is deciding which "Query" to exec.

Comment: @tbone Also, if you are interested in learning more about SQLCLR, check out this series of articles on SQL Server Central: [Stairway to SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Authors/Articles/Solomon_Rutzky/294002/) (free registration required). And if you want to play around with more SQLCLR functionality without having to write it yourself, check out the Free version of the [SQL#](http://www.SQLsharp.com/) library (which I am the author of).

Comment: This is awesome, thank you.  I tried some today and it is like nirvana, BUT (as I posted on another question and will repeat here):  So I tried tackling this remote SP call with dynamic SQL today with SQL CLR using integrated auth and immediately ran into this issue: Kerberos Protocol Transition and Constrained Delegation. technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345135%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Comment: And will be checking out both your links, that library looks very interesting.

Comment: @tbone I replied to that other comment saying that there are a few ways around that issue. One of which is to enable Delegation, and in one of the Stairway to SQLCLR articles I provide a link in the "Additional Reading" section at the bottom to another article on SQL Server Central (by someone else) that walks you through setting up Delegation. Gotta run. Will check back tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, got my delegation working today, once you figure it all out there's really almost nothing to it.  Although, our servers were all already configured for Kerberos.  Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: @tbone No problem. Glad you got the delegation working :). I just added an update to better explain the code structure I am talking about.

Comment: Thanks @srutzky - my understanding of it is that you have to disconnect your impersonation BEFORE the SqlContext.Pipe.Send though.  Which screws me up a bit because I had been doing cross DB joins to the metadata, but since I'm now down in C# it's not a problem, there's several way to accomplish that.  Your advice has been extremely helpful - once you know how the magic of to do it it's "easy", but there's not too many people out there with your knowledge (including MS documentation), *and* who write about it, so many  thanks.

Comment: @tbone Yes, sorry, you do indeed have to undo the ImpersonationContext prior to using `SqlPipe` again. However, that "undo"  can be done immediately after opening the external connection (even if points back into the same instance). I have updated both sections of pseudo-code in my answer to reflect this while keeping the dispose of the ImpersonationContext in the `finally` block. I don't see how that would be a problem as getting the metadata should be done before opening the Query connection. If it is, then you can always gather the data into local variables/collections first. And Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a sql statement on every database in a instance you can use (the unsupported, unofficial, but widely used) `exec sp_MSforeachdb`  like this:

```
EXEC sp_Msforeachdb 'use [?];  select * from users'
```

This will be the equivalent of going through every database through a

```
use db...
go
select * from users
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem because I googled for many, many hours, and found several people trying to do exactly the same thing as asked in the question.

Most common responses:

- Why would you want to do that?
- You **can not** do that, you **must** fully qualify your objects names

Luckily, I stumbled upon the answer, and it is brutally simple.  I think part of the problem is, there are so many variations of it with different providers & connection strings, and there are so many things that could go wrong, and when one does, the error message is often not terribly enlightening.

Regardless, here's how you do it:

If you are using static SQL:

```
select * from OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI','Server=ServerName[\InstanceName];Database=AdventureWorks2012;Trusted_Connection=yes','select top 10 * from HumanResources.Department')
```

If you are using Dynamic SQL - since OPENROWSET does not accept variables as arguments, you can use an approach like this (just as a contrived example):

```
declare @sql nvarchar(4000) = N'select * from OPENROWSET(''SQLNCLI'',''Server=Server=ServerName[\InstanceName];Database=AdventureWorks2012;Trusted_Connection=yes'',''@zzz'')'
set @sql = replace(@sql,'@zzz','select top 10 * from HumanResources.Department')
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Noteworthy:  In case you think it would be nice to wrap this syntax up in a nice Table Valued function that accepts @ServerName, @DatabaseName, @SQL - you cannot, as TVF's resultset columns must be determinate at compile time.

Relevant reading:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/wardpond/archive/2005/08/01/the-openrowset-trick-accessing-stored-procedure-output-in-a-select-statement.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/wardpond/archive/2009/03/20/database-programming-the-openrowset-trick-revisited.aspx

**Conclusion:**
OPENROWSET is the only way that you can 100% avoid at least some full-qualification of object names; even with EXEC AT you still have to prefix objects with the database name.

Extra tip:  The prevalent opinion seems to be that OPENROWSET shouldn't be used "because it is a security risk" (without any details on the risk).  My understanding is that the risk is only if you are using SQL Server Authentication, further details here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187873%28v=sql.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

*When connecting to another data source, SQL Server impersonates the login appropriately for Windows authenticated logins; however, SQL Server cannot impersonate SQL Server authenticated logins. Therefore, for SQL Server authenticated logins, SQL Server can access another data source, such as files, nonrelational data sources like Active Directory, by using the security context of the Windows account under which the SQL Server service is running. Doing this can potentially give such logins access to another data source for which they do not have permissions, but the account under which the SQL Server service is running does have permissions. This possibility should be considered when you are using SQL Server authenticated logins.*

Comment: Regarding "In case you think it would be nice to wrap this syntax up in a nice Table Valued function...": while it is true that the result set cannot change, you also cannot do Dynamic SQL in a T-SQL function ;-). And, `OPENROWSET` is not the only way around this. I detail another approach in my answer :).

Comment: Here's an interesting question @srutzky - with OpenRowset, I can have an Indeterminate (colums) resultset (at least I think I can, maybe I need to double check?), but no other approach can do this.  I can totally see why it is discouraged, but should it be technologically banned?  (Assuming I'm not totally misunderstading reality.)

Comment: Regarding "no other approach can do this": not necessarily true. The idea that I suggested also allows for a dynamic result set. The difference is that `OPENROWSET` is a function that returns a table that can be easily interacted with whereas I suggested a SQLCLR stored proc which cannot be JOINed to (unless you want to get crafty and use OPENQUERY / OPENROWSET to call the local server--loopback--to execute the SQLCLR proc, but not sure if they allow for calling SQLCLR). Still, OPENROWSET / OPENQUERY have restrictions on what the SQL they exec can do whereas the SQLCLR proc can exec anything.

Comment: But from the SQL server perspective a CLR SP is like any other isn't it, so you can't join to it?  And if it is a TVF, then even in CLR you are still restricted to a static set of returned columns, no?  I've never tried wrapping a SP in a CTE but doubt that would work.

Comment: Yes, a SQLCLR stored proc cannot be used in a SELECT / JOIN / etc. Also correct that a TVF needs a static result set. The benefit of `OPENROWSET` is that it is a function so can be interacted with more easily. But it shouldn't be a problem here to use a Stored Proc since that can be used in an `INSERT INTO TableName EXEC StoredProcName`. If queries return different result sets for different tables, as long as all fields are returned and in the same order then you just need the table name to build a dynamic query of `'INSERT INTO '+@Table+' EXEC Proc '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@QueryID)`, right?

Comment: "then you just need the table name to build a dynamic query..." Agreed, just for some reason embedding temp tables into dynamic sql feels a bit off to me, and considering you can do it with openrowset, I wish the (option* would be there with standard sql.  I realize *why* it is from a performance perspective, I just wish they'd allow you out of that cage when you want to, without using openrowset (the motivation is a human nature thing moreso than technical - getting a DBA to allowed cross server openrowset isn't easy!).

Comment: In your opinion, is there a good legitimate technical reason to not allow cross server openrowset?

Comment: "embedding temp tables into dynamic sql feels a bit off": why? If they are created prior to executing the dynamic SQL they can be quite useful. -- "is there a good _legitimate_ technical reason to not allow cross server openrowset?": I don't know. There could be, but I haven't found anything specific, just the same generic statements said of SQLCLR being a "security risk" with no actual evidence to back it up. If I had to guess I would suspect that it is difficult to restrict who can use it and for what. Why not ask the DBA(s) who won't allow it for their _specific_ reasoning :-D.

Comment: The "specific" reason was "it's a security risk", and also, it "isn't recommended".  :)

Comment: Was that a joke, or were they just being flippant because you had annoyed them with a question in the first place? If not, are they aware of the definition of "specific"?

Comment: Haha, in my experience it's just no that uncommon kneejerk reaction most DBA's have!